# Installing R package from local binaries

Tags: r, installation, binaries, renv

I downloaded `renv_1.0.2.tar.gz` to my local machine and then tried to install it with

```
install.packages(file.choose(), repos=NULL)
```

I got back the following error message:

```
# Bootstrapping renv 0.15.2 --------------------------------------------------
Warning: unable to access index for repository https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/windows/contrib/4.3:
  cannot open URL 'https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/windows/contrib/4.3/PACKAGES'
Warning: unable to access index for repository https://cloud.r-project.org/src/contrib:
  cannot open URL 'https://cloud.r-project.org/src/contrib/PACKAGES'
* Downloading renv 0.15.2 ... FAILED
Error in bootstrap(version, libpath) : failed to download renv 0.15.2
Calls: source ... eval.parent -> eval -> eval -> eval -> eval -> bootstrap
Execution halted
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘C:/Users/some_user/Downloads/renv_1.0.2.tar.gz’ had non-zero exit status
```

What does it mean and how can I fix it?

**UPDATE**

I also download binary `renv_0.15.2.tar.gz`
and tried:

```
install.packages("C:/Users/some_user/Downloads/renv_0.15.2.tar.gz", repos=NULL)
```

but got back similar error:

```
# Bootstrapping renv 0.15.2 --------------------------------------------------
Warning: unable to access index for repository https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/windows/contrib/4.3:
  cannot open URL 'https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/windows/contrib/4.3/PACKAGES'
Warning: unable to access index for repository https://cloud.r-project.org/src/contrib:
  cannot open URL 'https://cloud.r-project.org/src/contrib/PACKAGES'
* Downloading renv 0.15.2 ... FAILED
Error in bootstrap(version, libpath) : failed to download renv 0.15.2
Calls: source ... eval.parent -> eval -> eval -> eval -> eval -> bootstrap
Execution halted
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘C:/Users/some_user/Downloads/renv_0.15.2.tar.gz’ had non-zero exit status
```

Why is it trying to download the same package/binary?